# Pip: force installation of package version from a git repo

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am facing the problem to install a package based on a specific commit hash from Github.
This works great if the used venv does not already contain the installed package:

```
pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/user/pyckagexyz.git@1234567890032ab36c732dc32d9c257d401e71b0
```

This installs `pyckagexyz` and it's dependencies if it does not yet exist in the used venv. If it already exists this command does nothing. I also tried without success

```
pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir git+https://github.com/user/pyckagexyz.git@1234567890032ab36c732dc32d9c257d401e71b0
```

=> No effect

```
pip install --upgrade --force git+https://github.com/user/pyckagexyz.git@1234567890032ab36c732dc32d9c257d401e71b0
```

=> Installation fails because on of the dependencies can't be installed.

The only workaround I have found so far is to uninstall the package before re-installing it or to first install the package without dependencies and force `--no-deps --force` and then again a second time without force and dependencies to make sure all dependencies are present.

Is there no other way to say pip to install the selected version of a packet and overwrite an installed version?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [`--force-reinstall`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-force-reinstall) option with pip install?

`pip install --force-reinstall git+https://github.com/user/pyckagexyz.git@1234567890032ab36c732dc32d9c257d401e71b0`

From the pip docs:

> `--force-reinstall`
>
> Reinstall all packages even if they are already up-to-date.